# Telegrapher's equation and complex wave equations

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

I am not sure if this falls into engineering or physics, but since I am confused more about the underlining mathematics, I am posting it here. For the transmission of a TEM wave, telegraphers equations are derived for the propagation of current and voltage over an infinitely small region of a transmission wire:

$$-\frac{\partial v(z,t)}{ \partial z} = R i(z,t) + L \frac{\partial i(z,t)}{\partial t} --- (1)$$

$$-\frac{\partial i(z,t)}{\partial z} = G v(z,t) + C \frac{\partial v(z,t)}{ \partial t} -- (2)$$

Often what is done is "complexifying" the voltage and current signal such that:

$$v(z,t) = Re(V(z)e^{i \omega t}) \hspace{1cm} i(z,t) = Re(I(z) e^{i \omega t})$$

Now, the phasor part is used to solve the equation yielding an equation of the form:

$$\frac{d^2 V(z)}{dz^2} = (R + i \omega L)(G + i \omega C) V(z) = \gamma^2 V(z)$$

Which is claimed to be a wave equation since the solution will be of the form: $V_0^+ e^{-\gamma z} + V_0^- e^{\gamma z}$. To convince myself that this is indeed some sort of travelling wave take the rightward travelling component and convert it back to the time domain as follows ($\gamma = \beta + i\alpha$):

$$Re(V_0^+ e^{-(\beta + i\alpha)} e^{i \omega t}) = V_0^+ e^{-\beta} \cos(\alpha + \omega t)$$

However, when I look at the original equations (1) and (2), and try to create a wave function in the original sense ($\partial^2_{xx} f = \alpha \partial_{tt}^2 f$), I get:

$$\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial z^2} = -LC \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} - GR v  + (-RC - GL) \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$$

Which obviously does not have the traditional form that I know how to solve, nor do I recognize the solution I got using phasors. Could someone help me conceptually reconcile this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the telegraph equation does not look like the usual form of the wave equation because you have included *Ohmic losses* represented by $R$ and $G$ in the conductor and in the medium, resp. Had you constrained yourself to look at the lossless case $R=0$ and $G=0$ you would have gotten the 1D wave equations in its lossless form. Now it is possible to include the *Ohmic losses* in the medium by making the $\epsilon$ and $\mu$ complex but to include conductor losses you would have to change the boundary conditions. See this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/744846/why-is-the-phase-velocity-in-a-transmission-line-not-affected-by-its-geometry/744866#744866).

Answer (score 1):

Your last displayed equation is correct. The solutions of the telegrapher's  equation describe damped (decaying) waves whose phase velocity depends on frequency unless the [Heaviside condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_condition) $LG=RC$ is satisfied. They do not satisfy the usual wave equation unless both $R$ and $G$ are zero.